# Formula for nth Pontryagin class

Tags: differential-geometry, characteristic-classes

For the first Pontryagin classes we have:
$$ p_0=1 \\
p_1 = -\tfrac{1}{8\pi^2}\text{Tr}(F^2)\\
p_2=\tfrac{1}{128 \pi^4}(\text{Tr}(F^2)^2-2\text{Tr}(F^4))\\
p_3 = -\tfrac{1}{3072 \pi^6} (\text{Tr}(F^2)^3 - 6\text{Tr}(F^2)\text{Tr}(F^4) + 8 \text{Tr}(F^6))$$

I want a formula for the $p_n$ Pontryagin class. I have tried using the Newton-Girard formulas, specifically:
$$ p_k = (-1)^{k-1}ke_k+\Sigma_{i=1}^{k-1} (-1)^{k-1+i}e_{k-i}p_i$$

I had assumed that $e_n=(\tfrac{1}{2\pi})^{2n}\text{Tr}(F^{2n})$ but this does not give the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

I personally define the Pontryagin classes in terms of the Chern classes:

Let $\pi : E \to X$ be a real vector bundle. Then

$$p_i(E)= (-1)^i c_{2i}(E\otimes_{\mathbb R} \mathbb C) \in H^{4i}(X;\mathbb R)$$

p19 of these (excellent) [course notes](https://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/~or257/teaching/notes/Kthy.pdf) on characteristic classes and topological K-theory is where this comes from.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I was looking for something more along the lines of Equation 3.4 in this paper: https://www.gradmath.org/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/Sati-et-al-GJM-2018.pdf